# Expensive Calculation Program Operand Confusion

Tags: python, while-loop, calculator, operands

What i'm trying to do is have an initial input take a number, then proceed to take numbers that are entered afterwards until the loop is closed by entering 0. The output should be the Initial input, the amount entered added up, then subtracted from the Initial number.

I want to change the overall structure of the program as little as possible.

```
budget = float(input('Enter amount budgeted for the month: '))
spent = 0
total = 0
while spent >= 0:
    spent = float(input('Enter an amount spent(0 to quit): '))
    total += spent
    print ('Budgeted: $', format(budget, '.2f'))
    print ('Spent: $', format(total, '.2f'))
    if budget > total:
        difference = budget - total
        print ('You are $', format(difference, '.2f'), \
            'under budget. WELL DONE!')
    elif budget < total:
        difference = total - budget
        print ('You are $', format(difference, '.2f'), \
           'over budget. PLAN BETTER NEXT TIME!')
    elif budget == total:
        print ('Spending matches budget. GOOD PLANNING!')
```

Comment: You forgot `total += spent` in the loop.

Comment: Also, you want to loop `while spent != 0` - which means you need to initialize `spent` to something other than `0`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I did have "total += spent" in there, my bad I copied over the wrong window. I've tried to change the initial from 0 and it just breaks it over all. Thank you for pointing out that missing part though!

Comment: Your edits have changed alot...I will type an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to loop until user enters `0`. You can use a loop that breaks on `0`:

```
while True:
    spent = float(input('Enter an amount spent(0 to quit): '))
    if spent == 0: break
    total += spent
```

Or loop until `spent` is 0. This means initializing it to some non-zero value.

```
spent = -1
while spent != 0:
    spent = float(input('Enter an amount spent(0 to quit): '))
    total += spent
```

Also, all the other code should be outside the loop:

```
budget = float(input('Enter amount budgeted for the month: '))
spent = -1
total = 0
while spent != 0:
    spent = float(input('Enter an amount spent(0 to quit): '))
    total += spent
print ('Budgeted: $', format(budget, '.2f'))
print ('Spent: $', format(total, '.2f'))
if budget > total:
    difference = budget - total
    print ('You are $', format(difference, '.2f'), \
                'under budget. WELL DONE!')
elif budget < total:
    difference = total - budget
    print ('You are $', format(difference, '.2f'), \
               'over budget. PLAN BETTER NEXT TIME!')
else:
    print ('Spending matches budget. GOOD PLANNING!')
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! You're a nerve saver! I'm still learning quite a bit and your multiple way answer really helps me understand the possibilities! I hope you have an awesome day! <3